# Does dask dataframe have any efficient way to group by one column and then join on this column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dask

I have a `dask.DataFrame` like this:

```
uid|name
1|A
2|A
3|B
4|C
```

I want to get following result:

```
uid|name
1|A|A_NEW_ID
2|A|A_NEW_ID
3|B|B_NEW_ID
4|C|C_NEW_ID
```

I try to get the result by the following way:

Firstly, I use `groupby` to get `name` table

```
df2 = df.groupby("name").reset_index()
```

I get a new DataFrame like following:

```
index|name
0|A
1|B
2|C
```

Then, I can join the two DataFrame.

```
final_df = df.join(df2,on="name")
```

However, my table is very large and field `name` is also a big field. `join` consumes too much resources. Is there any efficient way to do this?

Comment: I think in pandas you only need `df['new_id'] = df['name'].factorize()[0]`

Comment: @ansev does dask has any similar method? my dataframe is very big that one machine can not process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a small pandas dataframe already that maps uid's to names then a join between a dask dataframe and a pandas dataframe should be fast and efficient

If you are looking for a unique set of uids then I recommend.

```
df.uid.unique().compute()
```

Comment: Thx! Since my uid field is a large field,join on this field is too slow. So I choose to use to use stable hash method to generate id from raw data set. This will be much faster while my has a collision problem.